# netty is http parser re-usable and how?

Tags: netty

I need re-usable async http parsing code.  Does netty perhaps contain some api for just the parsing portion?  (I always have a belief that parsers should be separate and re-usable and not tied to the framework so I hope netty's is reusable as well).

ie. It would be great to feed in bytes like so and it returns null if
there is not yet enough bytes

```
private byte[] previousData;

byte[] data = incomingMergedWithPrevious(previousData);
HttpResponse resp = httpResponseParser.parse(data);
if(resp == null) {
    return; //we do not have full data to parse yet
}

//otherwise fire the response to someone else.
```

OR maybe I could re-use the code a different way.  All I know is I get
bytes that don't always have all the http headers yet since it is
asynch stuff.  Any way to parse stuff?

NOTE: Also, I want to do chunking so I am not sure it should return HttpResponse every time but maybe an List where one subclass is HttpHeaders and another is HttpChunk.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DecoderEmbedder](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/embedder/DecoderEmbedder.html) probably in conjunction with [HttpMessageDecoder](http://static.netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpMessageDecoder.html). There's an example on the DecoderEmbedder page. It sounds like you want to use the pollAll method. You'll need to check the type of each returned object if you want to process HttpResponse and HttpChunk messages differently.

Comment: it's too bad they didn't make it more of a component in the first place so their own tests didn't have to create a special class to test it :( but thanks very much for the great answer.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. You just need to add HttpContentDecompressor to the handler list in the correct order. So the list is HttpMessageDecoder,HttpContentDecompressor. Calling pollAll should return the fully parsed and decompressed HTTP message or chunk.

Comment: ewwww, netty is throwing a runtime ReplayException on normal behavior of half packets coming in.....that's not very performant.  (they should really do what play did so the stack trace of that guy is not filled in).

Answer (score 0):

In the 4.1.x series the way to this is via the `EmbeddedChannel` class. Add a bunch of handlers to it then call the `writeInboundXXX` methods with `ByteBuf`s containing your raw http bytes. For instance to parse a request `new EmbeddedChannel(new HttpRequestDecoder, new MyHandler)` will cause your handler to receive decoded `HttpObjects`.

Comment: Nah, I wanted to avoid bringing all the netty classes in.  I ended up writing my own http1.1 and http2 parser in webpieces.  then I wrote an nio layer that knows nothing about http and finally a http client that re-uses the parser + nio layer tying it together so each is a composed piece and more re-usable not to mention way easier to maintain/test.